# Value 'C:Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)

Tags: java, android, gradle, flutter-test

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.2
```

Comment: you're missing "\" after "C:\" , It should be "C:\\" with the escape character.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the JDK and then reinstall JDK from the below mentioned site.

`https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/`

Or

```
click on File -> click on Project Structure

[![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97fbe.png][1]][1]

 -> click on SDK Location

[![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbBNQ.png][1]][1]

 -> click on Gradle JDK and select the JDK

[![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvnuK.png][1]][1]
```